Cannot set LC_* to default locale: No such file or directory
I just got my Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB installed with Debian 12 Bookworm, made WiFi, SSH, etc working as I wanted to, but I often get locale errors like with tasksel command:
root@rpi4:~# tasksel
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

I am unsure how to fix those, any tips? Thank you.

Even more errors with dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration:
root@rpi4:~# dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

As requested running dpkg-reconfigure locales:
root@rpi4:~# dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg-query: package 'locales' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed


Considering the very last line of my question (Thanks Chris Davies for the pointer):

/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed


It was easy just to install the locales package, which I took as a matter of course, yet it appears it is not.
Configuring locales was then the easiest part:
dpkg-reconfigure locales

